# How to get the html element from jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html like follows.

```
<tr class="meta-info" id="${page.id}">
    <td>
        <div class="pull-left">
         <font size="1">
             <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="like">Like</a>
         </font>
         </div>
         <div class="pull-right" style="font-size:1">
         <span class="badge"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>1</span>          
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to increase the number of likes when ever the user cliks on Like hyperlink.

Here is my jquery code. I want to know how i can get the html element from the jquery object.

```
$(".like").click(function(event){
    var parentTr = $(event.target).closest("tr");
    if(parentTr.length){
        var pageId = parentTr.attr("id");
        var spanEle = parentTr.get(0)+" div span:first-child"; ------(1)
        var lastNumber =  parseInt(spanEle.text());
        spanEle.text(lastNumber+1);
    }
});
```

I don't know if i am doing right on line which is marked 1.

Comment: Start here :) http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find

Comment: what element are you trying to retrieve when "Like" is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add an extra `<span>` tag so that you can replace the count without touching the adjacent icon

```
<span class="badge"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>
    <span class="like-count">1</span>
</span>
```

then you can address it

```
$(".like").click(function() {
    var spanEle = $(this).closest('tr').find('.like-count').first();
    if (spanEle.length) {
        var newCount = parseInt(spanEle.text());
        spanEle.text(newCount + 1);
    }
});
```

In an event handler, the `this` reference is `event.target`. You may be able to handle the element doesn't exist case neater than that too but that way's safe.

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rupw/VfCvK/

Comment: You should always pass the radix parameter when using parseInt ;)

Comment: To avoid octal strings? I suppose so, although in this case we're generating the string ourselves so that won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WeSr/1/)**

```
var lastNumber = parseInt(parentTr.find('.pull-right span').text(), 10);
```

You code will look like:

```
$(".like").click(function(event) {
    var parentTr = $(event.target).closest("tr");
    if (parentTr.length) {
        var pageId = parentTr.attr("id");
        var spanEle = parentTr.find('.pull-right span');
        var lastNumber =  parseInt(spanEle.text(), 10);
        spanEle.text(lastNumber + 1);
     }
});
```

Update:  If you wish to keep the `<i>` tag then use:

```
spanEle.html(spanEle.html().replace(lastNumber, lastNumber + 1));
```

insteadof : `spanEle.text(lastNumber + 1);`

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/GSJJw/)

Comment: Won't that destroy the `<i>` tag when you set the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(".like").click(function(event) {
    var parentTr = $(event.target).closest("tr");
    if (parentTr.length) {
        var pageId = parentTr.attr("id");
        var spanEle = parentTr.first('.badge');
        var lastNumber =  parseInt(spanEle.text(), 10);
        spanEle.text(lastNumber + 1);
    }
});
```

If the span element always has that classname then it will find the first (only?) one and return an int value of the text within.